# Javascript scroll to center or scroll to body

Tags: javascript

I am using

```
document.body.style.transform = 'scale(0.8)';
```

to decrease page size, and now I get scroll bars on the browser, I need it to scroll to center or scroll to body, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.scrollTo( 0, screen.height/2 );
```

or if you want center center:

```
window.scrollTo( screen.width/2, screen.height/2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
```

- y-coord: vertical scrolling
- x-coord: horizontal scrolling